# Why Doesn't my Integration to Square Root Tan(x) Work?

Tags: integration

What is wrong with this solution?
https://www.mathcha.io/editor/egPXHEXSj3CD1ip1

$$I=\int \sqrt{\tan x}dx$$
$u=\sqrt{\tan x}\Rightarrow \frac{2u}{u^2+1}du=dx$:
$$I=2\int\frac{u^2}{u^2+1}du$$
$$I=2\int\frac{u^2+1-1}{u^2+1}du$$
$$I=2\bigg(\int 1du-\int\frac1{u^2+1}du\bigg)$$
$$I=2\big(u-\arctan u\big)+C$$
$$I=2\sqrt{\tan x}-2\arctan\sqrt{\tan x}+C$$

Thanks!

Please do not link other solutions of this integral, I just want to know why the one I did is incorrect, thanks!

Comment: Figuring out LaTeX is pretty much a requirement for using this site. Plus, you'll gain a great skill if you ever have to write-up math in the future.

Comment: I added the LaTex as an edit. Take a look at it so you can see how it's done.

Answer (score 4):

$\cos^2 x \neq \frac{1}{1+(\sqrt{\tan{x}})^2}$.  $\cos^2 x = \frac{1}{1+(\sqrt{\tan{x}})^4} = \frac{1}{1+u^4}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$u=\sqrt{\tan x}\implies x= \tan ^{-1}\left(u^2\right)\implies dx=\frac{2 u}{u^4+1}\,du$$
$$I=\int \sqrt{\tan x}\,dx=2\int \frac{ u^2}{u^4+1}\,du=\int \frac{ u^2}{\left(u^2-\sqrt{2} u+1\right) \left(u^2+\sqrt{2} u+1\right)}\,du$$ Now, partial fraction decomposition
$$I=\frac 1 {\sqrt 2}\left(\int \frac{u}{u^2-\sqrt{2} u+1} \,du-\int \frac{u}{u^2+\sqrt{2} u+1}\,du \right)$$ which becomes to be quite easy.

Answer (score 0):

In your 2nd step you wrote,
$$u=\sqrt{\tan x}\Rightarrow \frac{2u}{u^2+1}du=dx$$

Actually as $u=\sqrt{\tan x}$,
$$du=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\tan x}} {{\sec^2}x}\;dx\quad\Rightarrow\quad dx=2\frac{\sqrt{\tan x}}{{\sec^2} x}du$$

$$\Rightarrow dx=\frac{2u}{{1+\tan^2} x}du \quad\Rightarrow\quad dx=\frac{2u}{1+({\sqrt{\tan x}})^4}du$$

Hence, $$u=\sqrt{\tan x}\quad\Rightarrow\quad \frac{2u}{u^4+1}du=dx$$
I think that is the part where a mistake has ocurred in your solution.